# How to get the data from "share picture via" dialog on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've added the intent-filter.
And when I tap "share" in the Gallery, it will launch my activity.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But I don't know how to get the correct data from the current intent.
Any helps?

EDIT: Sorry, missing "picture" in the question

Comment: Please be more specific. Have you added IntentFilter to your BroadcastReceiver or put that in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Sorry, I've modified my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put data in Intent with `intent.putExtra(..)` and get data with `intent.getXyzExtra(..)` where xyz dependt on the type: can be String, int, array, etc..

Check the [Intent docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).