# How can I to handle the "share via" dialog request from other app?

Tags: android, listener, handle, share, sharing

I added the intent-filter to ApplicationManifest.xml to take my app to "Share via" Dialog:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

How can I handle the request from another app.

1 Is it possible to differentiate between directly app-start  and  sharing start?

2 How to get access to sharing data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182299/how-to-get-the-data-from-share-picture-via-dialog-on-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In onCreate you can call [getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) to see if there is any data in the bundle. Use the [getData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData%28%29) method to retrieve a Uri or one of the get...Extra methods to retrieve any other expected data.

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.main);
    ...
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Uri data = i.getUri(); 
    if(data != null) {
    // do something interesting
    }
    /* or */
    String text = i.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    / * do something interesting with the text */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding question 1: in direct app-start case, the intent action would not be SEND.

for question 2 see my comment.