# How do I add my app to the Android 'share photo' option?

Tags: android, dialog, share, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Share Via Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog)

For example, when you hit share photo, it gives you a list of options to share through (Instagram, Messaging, Gmail, etc.).  I want my app to appear under these 'share' options after it is installed to the device.

I tried searching for it on Google, but I'm unfamiliar with any of the terminology so my search result terms are worded too strangely to be specific.

Comment: @ArtemStorozhuk, @Sam, @Jaguar It is not `possible duplicate` of question on the link, it is different question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this intent filter to your activity in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: How do you do the same for iOS instead of Android?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not an iOS dev.

Answer (score 2):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182299/how-to-get-the-data-from-share-picture-via-dialog-on-android) on StackOverflow. In the question you will see what you have to add to the manifest and in the first answer you will find how to retreive the data in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Adding an Easy Share action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)