# How to add PhoneGap apps at Androids sharing interface

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am looking for an interface / PhoneGap plugin (or any idea), to pass images from the gallery directly to the phonegap app.

I am already using the cordova camera plugin in my app, however I am looking for a way without selecting images out of the app.

To make it a bit more clearly what I am looking for, please see the image below.

The app runs on Cordova 3.0.

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Peter

[image: Example image]

Comment: unrelated, where could I get that background pic?

Answer (score 3):

The correct definition in the AndroidManifest.xml file is

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
</intent-filter>
```

Including the mimeType did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

It should work the same way for native as it does for phonegap/cordova.

Looking at a different post on stackoverflow, I believe you have to add the following intent to your activity in your Android manifest file.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I got this info from [How do I add my app to the Android 'share photo' option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350857/how-do-i-add-my-app-to-the-android-share-photo-option)

Comment: Did this solution work for anyone? I tried adding this intent-filter with a simple PhoneGap app but the app never appears in the share menu.

Comment: adding mimetype does the trick for me. I dont figure out how to get the shared file in my app

Answer (score 0):

@Jude Osborn  and @Sivkumar , make sure you have added the intent filter to main activity ( tag with attribute android:name="MainActivity". Also see this plugin.

https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent

and you will have to take the edits from pull request (specially the one for EXTRA_STREAM, and the Plugin.xml ) because at the time I am writing this, the plugin authr has not taken the pull requests yet.