# How to show your cordova/ionic app in this share menu of ios?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Sorry for maybe subjective question, but I really don't know what to google for.

So.. I want to put my ionic application here in this menu:

[image]

To be able to send files from any other app to my app, and to accept them.

I have found that for Android there is some [cordova-plugin-intent](https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent) plugin. In description it says how to put it in iOS open-in menu, which I succeeded... But its never listed here. Its in submenu of second row greyed icons, called open-in.

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910059/add-phonegap-app-to-share-menu-on-android-and-ios & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478769/how-to-add-phonegap-apps-at-androids-sharing-interface

Comment: Yes, this is it for Android, I already found it...But I didnt have luck to find solution for iOS, other then "open-in" submenu.

Comment: @DraganMalinovic i am trying to implement the same.. can you guide me in this issue.

Comment: I still didn't find way to do this, so unfortunately I have nothing new to share.