# How to get listed my ionic app in the share menu in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 3 app, where in i want the app to be placed in the share list in iPhone similarly like this,
[image]

This Share option should be placed while the User access the gallery and then when pressed on share button my ionic app should be placed along with whatsapp, facebook etc.

I have went through so many links to find out the answer ,

[Make Ionic app appear in “Share” list and receive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712312/make-ionic-app-appear-in-share-list-and-receive-data) : This will work for android phones only ( web -intent works only for android)

[My app inside iMessage UIActivityViewController [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991990/my-app-inside-imessage-uiactivityviewcontroller)
 I have tried to add this answer but i didn't got the info.plist file in my folder structure.

As said before i am using Ionic 3 framework, Is there any external plugin that i need to install to add my ionic app in share list ( in iPhone ).

Is there are any suitable docs available so that i can be able to get the desired result.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `Share Extension` may be helpful

Comment: @Nullable Can you please elaborate?

Comment: [Share Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html) is a plugin solution for iOS native. I don't know if it suits you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show my cordova app in IOS share menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843750/how-to-show-my-cordova-app-in-ios-share-menu)

Comment: You need to follow the guide shared by nullable.

Answer (score 3):

For the Ionic 3 framework, you still set up an Xcode project. These steps are nothing to do with The Framework. It's all about That Xcode project which you set up and build. If you don't [Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios) is the Ionic link.

Now Once you have the Xcode project.

Go to **File -> New -> Target**

In the Application Extention section, you will see **Share Extension** Click and Next,

Fill the required information. Now run your application (*This will install the extension in the simulator or device*) put the app in the background and go to the gallery, open any image and click the share button. Check if you can see your application name/icon in the list. Check the following screenshots.
[image: Screenshot for adding extention] 
[image: Screenshot for checking extention]

Now you need to follow apple guidelines for developing a share extension [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html).

Comment: You have a good point with this, maybe just add this as an option https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith . It depends on the need and the experience of the developer in which way to choose.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the image data from ios into ionic framework?