# Android share via my webview application

Tags: android, webview, share, image-uploading

How to implement a function, which allows from android image gallery share image to my webview application and upload it to the server?

E.g. I'm browsing through my android image gallery, on a specific image I click "share" button, then in a "Share via" window I select my webview application, which opens a specific view with packages list, then I select a package and the image is uploaded to the server with the selected package's id.

So, is it possible to create this functionality as described above? Or maybe it's only possible to upload an image via regular file chooser?

I'm quite new to android development, so any help where should I start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should Help :

[How to get the data from "share picture via" dialog on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182299/how-to-get-the-data-from-share-picture-via-dialog-on-android)

So now that you have sent the Picture and Received it using Intent - You can use your own Code to Upload it to server. Say you have a Check Box to select the Packages - Use the corresponding Information and Upload the Image.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can pick image from this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/)  and make you activity in share list by setting the intent filter in activity tag and then apply you logic for uploading the image

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />     
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

hopefully it will help you